# Print UPC-A without elongated guard bars using ZPL

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I'm trying to print a UPC-A barcode from a Zebra printer using ZPL.
It always comes out with elongated guard bars like this:
[image]

I need it to print like a Code 128 style where all the lines are the same length but encoded UPC-A style:
[image]

Here is a basic ZPL:
^XA
^BY3^BUN,70,N,N,N,A
^FD42222200439^FS
^XZ

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more details about the requirement, and why you need this?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I have seen to get rid of the descents on the guard bars is to draw over them with a white rectangle.  This is straightforward to do with UPC-A since it is a fixed width barcode (95 modules wide) and the descenders are 5 modules in height.  Since you are using `^BY3`, we need to multiply those numbers by 3, giving a width of 285px and a height of 15px for the descenders.

The example below uses `^FT` to position the barcode by its lower left corner.  Note that guard bars extend *below* that position.  Then we draw a white rectangle on top of the guard bar descents at the same origin, this time using `^FO`:

```
^XA 
^FT50,200^BY3^BUN,70,N,N,N^FD42222200439^FS
^FO50,200^GB285,15,15,W^FS
^XZ
```

Here is how it looks using the [labelary emulator](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&rotation=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EBY3%0A%5EFT50%2C200%5EBUN%2C70%2CN%2CN%2CN%5EFD42222200439%5EFS%0A%5EFO50%2C200%5EGB285%2C15%2C15%2CW%5EFS%0A%5EXZ).

Comment: That's a brilliant idea! Very creative!

Comment: Thanks.  I actually use this technique in production due to supply chain requirements.

Comment: This is fabulous.  Thanks Mark!  I was wondering if you could draw over it but did not know you could draw in white!
I also had appearance requirements from the business.  I suspect it's to visually differentiate it from other tags/labels but I'm not certain why.